# Question about pronunciation

Tags: discussion

Is it okay to ask questions about pronunciation?
Dispite some astonishing resources like  [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Russian), sometimes I find words which are tricky and I can't help but  ask about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, as long as you show prior research effort and clearly demonstrate why do you think it's not enough.